# Create a link button with slack blocks api

Tags: slack

I want to have a slack button that will behave as a link, it will send user to my website when it clicked.
Is that possible with slack new api?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using [block kit](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder).
All you have to do is add a `button` inside `actions` and provide the `url`. On click it will redirect to https://google.com and also sends a request to slack api.

**Block Kit Code:**

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "Click me"

                    },
                    "style": "primary",
                    "value": "click_me",
                    "url":  "https://google.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Link Button]

Comment: So you have style primary and ? Where can I get the list :) ?